# VCR is returning UnhandledHTTPRequestError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a site that can save links submitted by users. The create action takes a url, and pulls data from the og:tags in the html. The app itself works fine, but I'm having trouble testing it in RSpec with VCR.

The test passes fine without VCR, but takes very long (the actual code has multiple HTTP requests). 
When I try to run my test with VCR, I get the following error. How can I fix this issue?

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'submit'
VCR::Error::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
   ================================================================================
   An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
     GET http://espn.go.com/golf/masters13/story/_/id/9171606
```

**links_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(params[:link])
  if @link.save
    @link.title_from_url(@link.url)
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

**Link.rb**

```
def title_from_url(url)
  if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:title']").blank?
    self.title = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:title']").first.attributes["content"].text
    self.save      
  end
end
```

**link_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Link' do
  subject { page }
  before do
    visit root_path  
    click_link "create link"
  end
  describe "should be created with valid form" do
    VCR.use_cassette "link/create" do
      before do
        fill_in "enter url", with: "http://espn.go.com/golf/masters13/story/_/id/9171606"
        click_button "submit"
      end
      it { should have_selector('h2', text:'Adam Scott 1st Aussie to win Masters')}        
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/support/vcr_setup.rb**

```
VCR.configure do |c|   
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had 2 things wrong. First, needed to set my `Capybara.current_driver = :mechanize` via the `capybara-mechanize` gem. Second, needed to have the VCR block within an it block (instead of a describe). So the code below works.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Link' do
  subject { page }
  it "should be created with valid form" do
    VCR.use_cassette "link/create" do
      Capybara.current_driver = :mechanize
      visit root_path  
      click_link "create link"
      fill_in "enter url", with: "http://espn.go.com/golf/masters13/story/_/id/9171606"
      click_button "submit"
      page.should have_selector('h2', text:'Adam Scott 1st Aussie to win Masters')        
    end
  end
end
```